# Selenium нажать на элемент капчи

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, captcha

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажатие на check-box я как-то нашел а вот не могу нажать на жёлтого человечка который должен решить капчу не получается найти елемент и произвести клик.

```
<div id="rc-imageselect"><div class="rc-imageselect-response-field"></div><span class="rc-imageselect-tabloop-begin" tabindex="0"></span><div class="rc-imageselect-payload"><div class="rc-imageselect-instructions"><div class="rc-imageselect-desc-wrapper"><div class="rc-imageselect-desc-no-canonical" style="width: 352px; font-size: 16px;">Select all images with <strong style="font-size: 28px;">parking meters</strong></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-progress"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-challenge"><div id="rc-imageselect-target" class="rc-imageselect-target" dir="ltr" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><table class="rc-imageselect-table-33"><tbody><tr><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:0%; left: 0%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:0%; left: -100%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:0%; left: -200%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td></tr><tr><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:-100%; left: 0%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:-100%; left: -100%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:-100%; left: -200%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td></tr><tr><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:-200%; left: 0%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:-200%; left: -100%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td><td role="button" tabindex="0" class="rc-imageselect-tile" aria-label="Image challenge"><div class="rc-image-tile-target"><div class="rc-image-tile-wrapper" style="width: 126px; height: 126px"><img class="rc-image-tile-33" src="https://www.google.com:443/recaptcha/api2/payload?p=06AGdBq25P2tNloW_8Sc3oQmcsmqyv9tSy4fautKYuBNQ2-gWpeO5Z_WEGXiDuq28V1H6jSiUwZ4yVAh9wkPnoVX7Qnnhy0GgOScx9VDkc41UasTBrDMBPvlmUnDoVE5X03k8l3ow1trn5W0YYC1jK2Ls1JK6GN7x5a9O9BAE9ws53krPRdszIg96ksyF_O-dI1KYckRrVvZg6aT90vJ2BtjPyHWNSimaTm8NOURGZ0Ym5xR-fHASLZPc&amp;k=6LcjDn8UAAAAAO6WaVEQiKH0J3bacNuR9yByEgyd" style="top:-200%; left: -200%"><div class="rc-image-tile-overlay"></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-checkbox"></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div><div class="rc-imageselect-incorrect-response" style="display:none">Please try again</div><div class="rc-imageselect-error-select-more" style="display:none">Please select all matching images.</div><div class="rc-imageselect-error-dynamic-more" style="display:none">Please also check the new images.</div><div class="rc-imageselect-error-select-something" style="display:none">Please select around the object, or reload if there are none.</div></div><div class="rc-footer"><div class="rc-separator"></div><div class="rc-controls"><div class="primary-controls"><div class="rc-buttons"><div class="button-holder reload-button-holder"><button class="rc-button goog-inline-block rc-button-reload" title="Get a new challenge" value="" id="recaptcha-reload-button" tabindex="0"></button></div><div class="button-holder audio-button-holder"><button class="rc-button goog-inline-block rc-button-audio" title="Get an audio challenge" value="" id="recaptcha-audio-button" tabindex="0"></button></div><div class="button-holder image-button-holder"><button class="rc-button goog-inline-block rc-button-image" title="Get a visual challenge" value="" id="recaptcha-image-button" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></button></div><div class="button-holder help-button-holder"></div><div class="button-holder undo-button-holder"><button class="rc-button goog-inline-block rc-button-undo" title="Undo" value="" id="recaptcha-undo-button" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></button></div><div class="button-holder"><button class="rc-button goog-inline-block" tabindex="0" title="Solve the challenge" id="solver-button"></button></div></div><div class="verify-button-holder"><button class="rc-button-default goog-inline-block" title="" value="" id="recaptcha-verify-button" tabindex="0">Verify</button></div></div><div class="rc-challenge-help" style="display:none" tabindex="0"></div></div></div><span class="rc-imageselect-tabloop-end" tabindex="0"></span></div>
```

мой код на питон:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "google.com/recaptcha")]')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'recaptcha-anchor'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй не через xpath , а через класс нажать  class="rc-imageselect-response-field" и попробуй через нахождения элемента find_by  ,а не через WebDriverWait (это задержка в 10 секунд у тебя).Кстати на ютуб зайди напиши( решение капчи селениум) на англиских каналах уже давно без бустера на чистом селене быстро решаетца.Вот все подробно расписано:
https://youtu.be/As-_hfZUyIs

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал это когда переключился на фрейм. Так как чекбокс находится во фрейме

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='reCAPTCHA']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")).click();
```

Ломаю голову как отправить callback c решением) если вы уже решили эту проблему буду признателен за помощь)